# How to sort attribute options in Magento 2 alphabetically

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute

For example, if you have thousands of colors (options) in the `color` attribute, it becomes a pain to use the drag & drop sorting functionality.

I'd like to override the default sorting (based on option `position`) to sort by `attribute label` alphabetically for all attributes.

I did some digging around in core files, but couldn't locate the class or function which does this.

Any ideas where this functionality is inside Magento's core?

Comment: Hi,
Im also interested in this. Did you manage to find any solution?

Comment: @user1517598 No, what I ended up doing was to give all attribute options the same position (0) with SQL. This sorted the options alphabetically. Then I just moved the 1st option to the 2nd position via drag & drop, and all attributes got their position based on alphabet. This is just a "one time fix" but it might help...

Comment: Hi,

Appreciate the response. We have attributes with 100's of values. Your solution is good. I think Ill see if I can get some javascript written to resolve this.

For example. On an attribute view, when open, have a button that when selected, resorts the list either Asc or Desc

Then you select save.

Basically takes the array of values and re-orders list.

Ill update this post when I have something to show.

Cheers

Comment: @BrendanBell sounds like a reasonable solution. Would be great if you could share it when you're done. Cheers!

Comment: Lez, Did you ever find the answer for this? Is there code anywhere for this? Brendan Bell, where is your code?

Comment: @Jonathan sorry to say, but no... never had the time to try and create a button that would sort options alphabetically like Brendan did, so I can't help...

Answer (score 1):

you can download this module https://github.com/nhutnguyenvu/alphabet-option. It allows you can sort any attributes by alphabet (desc, asc) or position

Answer (score 0):

So I have had a development done to make the usability of product attributes with "many" options a lot simpler.

Essentially I have added Sort button, see below.
It takes the list of items and resorts in Alphabetical order.

**Before Change**

[image: Before Change]
**After Selecting Button**

[image: After Selecting Button]

After the list is resorted, just hit the save button.

If your interested in code, just message me to work something out.

Regards

Comment: Glad you found a permanent solution for this, but I'm not really interested in paid solutions, thanks for the offer though.

Comment: Hi Sir, I Nee this code